# how to use media query to seperate phone vs tablet portrait vs tablet landscape

Tags: css, media-queries

I use sass for styling and I have a main sass file which has @imports of various different scss files 
conditionally included with media queries.

### I am looking for ...

1. phone
2. all/most tablet (portrait), that behaves like the phone
3. all/most tablet (landscape)

### here is my media query:

```
@import "global";
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
    @import "styleguide";
    @import "phone";
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (orientation: portrait){

}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (orientation: landscape){

    @import "tablet-styleguide";
    @import "tablet";
}
```

### here's my result

1. I load the page on my landscaped tablet, and everything is fine
2. I rotate 90 deg, and it displays the portrait, which is also fine
3. I rotate back to landscape, and everything is still in portrait...,

### I've debugged for hours, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The largest width goes first - on top , then as the width's get smaller they go on the bottom.  Because a phone will pass all width tests , so will a tablet .  Your code will end up using the last media query every time no matter what device is being used

Comment: ok, i might have followed a wrong methodology, but i thoguht this was mobile first, so the 320px + css is needed for the tablet to look fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting your imports like this (instead of inside a media query):

```
@import url(foo.css) screen and (min-width:320px);
@import url(bar.css) screen and (min-device-width:768px) and (orientation:portrait);
@import url(blah.css) screen and (min-device-width:768px) and (orientation:landscape);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that instead of `min-device-wdith`, I should use `min-width`.